# String showing wrong length after going through function

Tags: php

I have the following function in my class.

```
public function checkPostcodeFormat($postcode) {
    if (strlen($postcode) === 7 && substr($postcode, 5) !== " ") {
        return substr($postcode, 0, 4) . ' ' . substr($postcode, 4, 3);
    } elseif (strlen($postcode) === 6 && substr($postcode, 4) !== " ") {
        return substr($postcode, 0, 3) . ' ' . substr($postcode, 3, 3);
    } else {
        return $postcode;
    }
}
```

If the postcode is returned via the substr functions it's fine, but if it's returned in the else section a `var_dump()` shows it to be the wrong length.

```
var_dump($_POST["postcode"]);
```

shows

```
string(7) "ab1 1ab"
```

Whereas

```
var_dump($class->checkPostcodeFormat($_POST["postcode"]));
```

shows

```
string(8) "ab1 1ab"
```

What could be causing the string to grow in length, if it's just being returned through the function?

Comment: If in doubt: check a `var_dump(bin2hex($string))`.

Comment: Store the return value in a variable and run -- `for ($i=0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {  var_dump($str[$i]); }` to inspect what's the causing the issue.

Comment: Found the culprit, `string(1) " " string(1) " "`. Why would simply passing it through the function create an extra space, which is invisible.

Comment: @BenFortune: Great. Could you explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @AmalMurali Currently have a database with UK postcodes(2.5m rows), the postcodes are in the format (AB1 1AB or AB12 1AB). I wanted to add a space if the input was something like (AB11AB or AB121AB).

Comment: @BenFortune: So, if the input is `AB11AB`, you want the output as `AB1 1AB` and if the input is `AB121AB` -- output should be `AB12 1AB`?

Comment: @AmalMurali Pretty much yeah. Is there any viable reason my function is adding the extra space?

Comment: Perhaps a simpler solution: `return preg_replace('/^(.+)(.{3})$/', '$1 $2', str_replace(' ', '', $postCode));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `$postcode` is  of the format `ab1 1ab`, then the first `if` condition will evaluate to `TRUE` and the code inside that `if` block will be executed. For the above input,  `substr($postcode, 5)`  will return the string `ab`. So, `substr($postcode, 5) !== " ")` will always be `TRUE` as long as the length of the post code is `7`. And you're just adding an additional space when returning the string.

It's a good idea to remove all the space before working on your strings. I've improved the function as follows:

```
public function checkPostcodeFormat($postcode) {
    // remove all spaces in the post code
    $postcode = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $postcode);

    if (strlen($postcode) === 6) {
        return substr($postcode, 0, 3).' '.substr($postcode, 3);
    } elseif (strlen($postcode) === 7) {
        return substr($postcode, 0, 4).' '.substr($postcode, 4);
    } 
}
```

Test cases:

```
var_dump( checkPostcodeFormat('AB11AB'));
var_dump( checkPostcodeFormat('AB121AB'));
```

Output:

```
string(7) "AB1 1AB"
string(8) "AB12 1AB"
```

Comment: @BenFortune: You're welcome. I've added a short explanation, too.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation:

your if condition is returning 8 characters string

```
substr($string, $start, $length)
```

So, when you input "ab1 1ab"

in if condition

```
1)substr($postcode, 0, 4) return "ab1 " <=== first space comes from here
2)then you appends space <=== another one from here
```

and then

```
3)substr($postcode, 4, 3) appends "1ab"
```

together they return "ab1  1ab" <=== two spaces between

Comment: The code itself works fine, it's the `else{return}` that's not working.

Comment: but according to the test case you have specified, i guess, the application enters in if case and not in else case as the input string length is exactly 7 and fifth character is not space.

Answer (score 0):

Your code duplicates spaces, Your return is "ab1  1ba", but browser shows only one.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/49a75148d3d5236359776b33a4701789dccd25bf

Comment: I already knew that. I was trying to find out why it was duplicating the spaces from just passing through the function.

Comment: Because of substr($postcode, 0, 4) . ' ' . substr($postcode, 4, 3); this line, the 4th symbol is ' ', and You adding another ' ' !!

Comment: change it to substr($postcode, 0, 3) . ' ' . substr($postcode, 4, 3); like it here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2913d5227258b77a88aea50b4af1c568cc0be457

Comment: @BenFortune: Please see my answer below.